# how to write a program using scanner class should print only string values but not int values

Tags: java

i want to write a program where scanner takes input of integers and strings at output it should not print integer value it has to print only string value..

input int value =6;
input string value ="hello"

output=hello

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int x= sc.nextInt(); 
String v=sc.nextLine();
String v1 =sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(x+v1);
```

Comment: What exactly do you think this does: System.out.println(x+v1); ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to print integer values, you can write a custom Printer class with overloaded `print` and `println` methods for numeric types, like this:

```
class MyPrinter{
  // constructors and stuff
  void print(int i){
    System.out.print('');
    // or you may as well just return;
  }
}
```

and if you dont want to print numbers **at all** you can also modify the function for `String` argument:

```
void print(String s){
  System.out.print(s.replaceAll("[0-9]+",""));
}
```

and this way, even if you concatenate numbers to your string, they won't be printed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print values in string format, than you should write it like this.

`System.out.println(v1);`

Because x is integer and v1 is string.

If you print this:

`System.out.println(x + v1);`

This is going to automaticly convert `x` to string and print both values concatenated as string.